# how to append text in ons template in onsen ui using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsen-ui

I am new in onsen UI I want to append some data to  when template is loaded by click or load function

I am tried it using Javascript and jquery but it did not work

please help

Thanks in advance

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator">


  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center" ><img src="img/logo-sg.jpg" /></div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <br>
       <p  >'Im building an app where I have the first 3 pages (login, register and password recover) without toolbar and sliding-menu. Inside of my app (logged pages) I want to provide the slide-menu, but I'm not achiving this goal. How can I do it?</p>
      <ons-button modifier="light" onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('login.html', { animation : 'slide' } )">
       Login Page
      </ons-button>
    </div>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
    <ons-template id="login.html">
  <ons-page>
     <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Log In</div>
        <div class="right"><ons-toolbar-button>Close</ons-toolbar-button></div>
      </ons-toolbar>

      <div class="login-form">

        <input type="email" id="uname" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Email" value="">
        <input type="password" id="pass" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Password" value="">
        <br><br>
        <ons-button modifier="large" id="btnSubmit"  onclick="SignIn();" class="login-button">Log In</ons-button>
        <br><br>
        <ons-button modifier="quiet" onclick="#" class="forgot-password">Forgot password?</ons-button>
        <ons-button modifier="quiet" onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('signup.html', { animation : 'slide' } )" class="forgot-password">SignUp</ons-button>
        <div style="text-align: center">
      <br />
      <ons-button modifier="light" onclick="myNavigator.popPage()">
        Back to Home
      </ons-button>
    </div>
      </div>




  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
    <ons-template id="signup.html">

    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
        <div class="center">Sign up</div>
      </ons-toolbar>

      <div class="formarea">
        <div class="form-row">
          <input type="text"  id="txtName" class="signup text-input--underbar width-full" placeholder="Name" value="">

        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <input type="text" id="txtNewUserName" class="signup text-input--underbar width-full" placeholder="Email" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <input type="password" id="txtNewPassword" class="text-input--underbar width-full" placeholder="Password" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="lucent">
          <p class="note">Password - 6 characters or more</p>
        </div>

        <div class="vspc form-row">
          <ons-button modifier="large--cta" onclick="SignUp();" >Sign up</ons-button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </ons-page>

    </ons-template>
    <ons-template id="dashbord.html">

    <ons-page>
    <input type="hidden" id="hfDasId" />
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
        <div class="center">MENU</div>
           <div class="right"><ons-button onclick="RedirectCart()"><img src="img/cart.png" onload="cartValue()" />(<span class="CartCount"></span>)</ons-button></ons-tab></div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <ons-row>




    <ons-col ><ons-button class="nobackgroud"  onclick="RedirectPurch()"><img src="img/my-account.jpg"></ons-button></ons-col>
    <ons-col><ons-button class="nobackgroud"  onclick="RedirectPurch()"><img src="img/purchase.jpg" ></ons-button></ons-col>

  </ons-row>
   <ons-row>
    <ons-col><ons-button class="nobackgroud"    onclick="RedirectPurch()"><img src="img/switch.jpg" ></ons-button></ons-col>
    <ons-col><ons-button class="nobackgroud"   onclick="RedirectPurch()"><img src="img/redemption.jpg" ></ons-button></ons-col>
      </ons-row>
      <ons-row>
    <ons-col><ons-button class="nobackgroud"   onclick="RedirectPurch()"><img src="img/account-statement.jpg" ></ons-button></ons-col>
    <ons-col><ons-button class="nobackgroud"   onclick="RedirectPurch()"><img src="img/chanhe-pin.jpg" ></ons-button></ons-col>
      </ons-row>
    </ons-page>

    </ons-template>
    <ons-template id="purchase.html">

    <ons-page>
    <input type="hidden" id="hfId" />
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
        <div class="center">MENU</div>
        <div class="right"><ons-button onclick="RedirectCart()"><img src="img/cart.png" onload="cartValue()" />(<span class="CartCount"></span>)</ons-button></ons-tab></div>
      </ons-toolbar>


  <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Scheme Type </td>
    <td>
        <select id="ddlSchemeType" >
            <option value="Equity">Equity</option>
            <option value="Redem">Redem</option>

        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Plan 
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="button-bar" style="width:200px; margin:8px auto 0;">
              <div class="button-bar__item">
                <input type="radio" name="Plan" checked>
                <div class="button-bar__button">Direct</div>
              </div>
              <div class="button-bar__item">
                <input type="radio" name="Plan">
                <div class="button-bar__button">Regular</div>
              </div>
            </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Scheme  </td>
    <td>
        <select id="ddlScheme">
            <option value="Kotak">Kotak</option>
            <option value="ICICI">ICICI</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Dividend 
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="button-bar" style="width:200px; margin:8px auto 0;">
              <div class="button-bar__item">
                <input type="radio" name="Dividend" checked>
                <div class="button-bar__button">Reinvest</div>
              </div>
              <div class="button-bar__item">
                <input type="radio" name="Dividend">
                <div class="button-bar__button">PayOut</div>
              </div>
            </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>
    Amount($) 
    </td>
    <td>
   <input type="text" id="txtAmt"  class="text-input--underbar width-full"  />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Payout bank </td>
    <td>
        <select id="ddlPayoutBank">
            <option value="ICICI">ICICI</option>
            <option value="PNB">PNB</option>
            <option value="SBI">SBI</option>
            <option value="HDFC">HDFC</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding:0px;" >
   <ons-button modifier="large" onclick="purchase();" >Submit</ons-button>


    </td>
    <td style="padding:0px;" >
   <ons-button modifier="large" >Reset</ons-button>

    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>


    </ons-page>

    </ons-template>
    <ons-template id="cart.html">

    <ons-page id="cart">

      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
        <div class="center">Cart</div>
        <div class="right"><img src="img/blank.png" onload="CartDetail()" /> </div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <a id="ab" href="#"></a>
      <table id="product"> </table> 


     <div id="tblProduct" style="display: none;" >

        <table>



            <tr class="data">

                <td class="Scheme">
                </td>
                <td class="Amount">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="btnDelete" type="button" value="Delete" />
                </td>


            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>


    </ons-page>

    </ons-template>
</body>
```

**jquery**

```
CartDetail = function () {
 var prod = $('#product');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:60595/api/purchase/?userId=" + parseFloat($("#hfDasId").val()), //local
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (index, Purchase) {



                            var $row = $('#tblProduct').find('.data').clone().attr("id", "row_" + Purchase.Id);
                            $row.find(".Scheme").html(Purchase.Scheme);
                            $row.find(".Amount").html(Purchase.Amount);
                            $row.find("#btnDelete").click(function () {


                                $.ajax({

                                    url: "http://localhost:60595/api/purchase/" + Purchase.Id, //local
                                    type: "PUT",
                                    success: function () {

                                        $row.remove();
                                    },
                                    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                                        alert(Purchase.Id);
                                        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                            alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                                        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                                        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                            alert('Time out error.');
                                        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                                        } else {
                                            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                                        }
                                    }

                                });

                            });
                            prod.append($row);
                        });

                    }


                });

            }
```

Comment: In the first template you are opening two different `<ons-page>` tags and closing only one. Also, please, make a small example where you show your problem rather than posting the whole app.

Comment: thanks for your comment what should i do resolve append data to <ons-template>

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told exactly what you did when you said

> I am tried it using Javascript and jquery but it did not work

Therefore, I assume you tried to add the script inside the template. If so [refer this question](http://I%20am%20tried%20it%20using%20Javascript%20and%20jquery%20but%20it%20did%20not%20work)

In anycase, a code pen recreation of the code you gave, which should work if your other image and localhost assets are in place. [link to my codepen](http://codepen.io/alokrajiv/pen/RPzZQb)

Complete the code or preferrable as @ Fran Dios commented try to recreate your issue in a smaller form so that we can understand try to solve your specific problem.

```js
angular.module('TestApp', ['onsen'])

.controller('cartController', function($scope) {
  $scope.CartDetail = function() {
    var prod = $('#product');
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:60595/api/purchase/?userId=" + parseFloat($("#hfDasId").val()), //local
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, Purchase) {

          var $row = $('#tblProduct').find('.data').clone().attr("id", "row_" + Purchase.Id);
          $row.find(".Scheme").html(Purchase.Scheme);
          $row.find(".Amount").html(Purchase.Amount);
          $row.find("#btnDelete").click(function() {

            $.ajax({

              url: "http://localhost:60595/api/purchase/" + Purchase.Id, //local
              type: "PUT",
              success: function() {

                $row.remove();
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                alert(Purchase.Id);
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                  alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                  alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                  alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                  alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                  alert('Time out error.');
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                  alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                  alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
              }

            });

          });
          prod.append($row);
        });

      }

    });

  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="TestApp">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator">

      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">
          <img src="img/logo-sg.jpg" />
        </div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <br>
        <p>'Im building an app where I have the first 3 pages (login, register and password recover) without toolbar and sliding-menu. Inside of my app (logged pages) I want to provide the slide-menu, but I'm not achiving this goal. How can I do it?</p>
        <ons-button modifier="light" onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('login.html', { animation : 'slide' } )">
          Login Page
        </ons-button>
      </div>

    </ons-navigator>
  </ons-page>
  <ons-template id="login.html">
    <ons-page>
      <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="center">Log In</div>
          <div class="right">
            <ons-toolbar-button>Close</ons-toolbar-button>
          </div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <div class="login-form">

          <input type="email" id="uname" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Email" value="">
          <input type="password" id="pass" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Password" value="">
          <br>
          <br>
          <ons-button modifier="large" id="btnSubmit" onclick="SignIn();" class="login-button">Log In</ons-button>
          <br>
          <br>
          <ons-button modifier="quiet" onclick="#" class="forgot-password">Forgot password?</ons-button>
          <ons-button modifier="quiet" onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('signup.html', { animation : 'slide' } )" class="forgot-password">SignUp</ons-button>
          <div style="text-align: center">
            <br />
            <ons-button modifier="light" onclick="myNavigator.popPage()">
              Back to Home
            </ons-button>
          </div>
        </div>


      </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
  <ons-template id="signup.html">

    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">Sign up</div>
      </ons-toolbar>

      <div class="formarea">
        <div class="form-row">
          <input type="text" id="txtName" class="signup text-input--underbar width-full" placeholder="Name" value="">

        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <input type="text" id="txtNewUserName" class="signup text-input--underbar width-full" placeholder="Email" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <input type="password" id="txtNewPassword" class="text-input--underbar width-full" placeholder="Password" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="lucent">
          <p class="note">Password - 6 characters or more</p>
        </div>

        <div class="vspc form-row">
          <ons-button modifier="large--cta" onclick="SignUp();">Sign up</ons-button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </ons-page>

  </ons-template>
  <ons-template id="dashbord.html">

    <ons-page>
      <input type="hidden" id="hfDasId" />
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">MENU</div>
        <div class="right">
          <ons-button onclick="RedirectCart()">
            <img src="img/cart.png" onload="cartValue()" />(<span class="CartCount"></span>)</ons-button>
          </ons-tab>
        </div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <ons-row>


        <ons-col>
          <ons-button class="nobackgroud" onclick="RedirectPurch()">
            <img src="img/my-account.jpg">
          </ons-button>
        </ons-col>
        <ons-col>
          <ons-button class="nobackgroud" onclick="RedirectPurch()">
            <img src="img/purchase.jpg">
          </ons-button>
        </ons-col>

      </ons-row>
      <ons-row>
        <ons-col>
          <ons-button class="nobackgroud" onclick="RedirectPurch()">
            <img src="img/switch.jpg">
          </ons-button>
        </ons-col>
        <ons-col>
          <ons-button class="nobackgroud" onclick="RedirectPurch()">
            <img src="img/redemption.jpg">
          </ons-button>
        </ons-col>
      </ons-row>
      <ons-row>
        <ons-col>
          <ons-button class="nobackgroud" onclick="RedirectPurch()">
            <img src="img/account-statement.jpg">
          </ons-button>
        </ons-col>
        <ons-col>
          <ons-button class="nobackgroud" onclick="RedirectPurch()">
            <img src="img/chanhe-pin.jpg">
          </ons-button>
        </ons-col>
      </ons-row>
    </ons-page>

  </ons-template>
  <ons-template id="purchase.html">

    <ons-page>
      <input type="hidden" id="hfId" />
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">MENU</div>
        <div class="right">
          <ons-button onclick="RedirectCart()">
            <img src="img/cart.png" onload="cartValue()" />(<span class="CartCount"></span>)</ons-button>
          </ons-tab>
        </div>
      </ons-toolbar>


      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Scheme Type</td>
          <td>
            <select id="ddlSchemeType">
              <option value="Equity">Equity</option>
              <option value="Redem">Redem</option>

            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Plan
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="button-bar" style="width:200px; margin:8px auto 0;">
              <div class="button-bar__item">
                <input type="radio" name="Plan" checked>
                <div class="button-bar__button">Direct</div>
              </div>
              <div class="button-bar__item">
                <input type="radio" name="Plan">
                <div class="button-bar__button">Regular</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Scheme</td>
          <td>
            <select id="ddlScheme">
              <option value="Kotak">Kotak</option>
              <option value="ICICI">ICICI</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Dividend
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="button-bar" style="width:200px; margin:8px auto 0;">
              <div class="button-bar__item">
                <input type="radio" name="Dividend" checked>
                <div class="button-bar__button">Reinvest</div>
              </div>
              <div class="button-bar__item">
                <input type="radio" name="Dividend">
                <div class="button-bar__button">PayOut</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Amount($)
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtAmt" class="text-input--underbar width-full" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Payout bank</td>
          <td>
            <select id="ddlPayoutBank">
              <option value="ICICI">ICICI</option>
              <option value="PNB">PNB</option>
              <option value="SBI">SBI</option>
              <option value="HDFC">HDFC</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding:0px;">
            <ons-button modifier="large" onclick="purchase();">Submit</ons-button>


          </td>
          <td style="padding:0px;">
            <ons-button modifier="large">Reset</ons-button>

          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>


    </ons-page>

  </ons-template>
  <ons-template id="cart.html" ng-controller="cartController as cartCtrl">

    <ons-page id="cart">

      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">Cart</div>
        <div class="right">
          <img src="img/blank.png" ng-click="CartDetail()" />
        </div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <a id="ab" href="#"></a>
      <table id="product"></table>


      <div id="tblProduct" style="display: none;">

        <table>


          <tr class="data">

            <td class="Scheme">
            </td>
            <td class="Amount">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input id="btnDelete" type="button" value="Delete" />
            </td>


          </tr>

        </table>

      </div>


    </ons-page>

  </ons-template>
</body>
```